# If I receive a hacked Pokemon over Wondertrade will it corrupt the game?

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation, cheats, pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

I got a shiny Rayquaza over Wondertrade. I noticed it didn't have the blue pentagon next to it. I've been told that's the sign of a hacked pokemon. Will it hurt my game in anyway because I have it?

Comment: [That doesn't mean it's a hacked pokemon](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/159648/whats-the-blue-pentagon-for-in-pokemon-xy/159650#159650)

Comment: There's a shiny [Event Rayquaza](http://www.serebii.net/events/dex/384.shtml), if your pokemon is in a Cherish ball (the red Pokeball) it's probably not a cheat. Anyway no, you don't risk anything receiving an hacked pokemon, don't worry.

Comment: No, it's just in a regular Pokeball. Thank you for the help!

Comment: While a regular Pokeball is hard to pull off, Shiny Rayquaza can totally be caught in HGSS. RNG is not that hard there, so it's not uncommon to see shiny Rayquaza originating from HGSS, which has no blue pentagon and can be in any ball available in HGSS (and there are a lot of those).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Blue_pentagon):

> A blue pentagon is a icon displayed on the summary screen of Pokémon **obtained in the Generation VI** games. Pokémon that are hatched, caught, or received as a gift in a Generation VI game will have a Blue [image: pentagon] icon on their summary screen near the markings. Prior to the release of Pokémon Omega Ruby and Alpha Sapphire, having a blue pentagon was referred to as being Kalos native.